# Is it required to mention all nodes host IP into the discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using the Elasticsearch version 6.4.2 and have 11 nodes across the cluster.

In elasticsearch.yml, does it required to mention the all nodes Host IP into discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts option?

Will, it affect the performance if all nodes have not to be mentioned into discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts?

What if I will mention the few of nodes Host IP into the discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts?

**discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts**: ["192.173.272.107", "192.173.272.108", "192.173.272.105", "192.173.272.101", "192.173.272.103","192.173.272.104"]

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` setting should only contain the list of all **master-eligible nodes**, but no data nodes.

That way when scaling out and adding new data nodes to your cluster, you don't need to modify the configuration of all existing data nodes.